# Is there a way to get request and response body of a http request for a microservices application?

Tags: node.js, microservices, trace

I have an application consisting of 2 microservices.

Is there a way I can get the request and response for each request received and sent by each of the microservice with minimal changes in code.

The application is in node.js.

I have tried some tracing frameworks but they only provide the timing information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express to implement your API backend server you can use the express-winston to intercept the request and response of each call.

In the example bellow a use the express winston to log out the request and response into the console.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const expressWinston = require('express-winston');

/**
 * Custom Wiston Express Middleware to log all requests and responses in the console.
 */
module.exports = async() => {
    // Creating middleware
    expressWinston.requestWhitelist.push('body');
    expressWinston.responseWhitelist.push('body');
    const wistonMiddleware = expressWinston.logger({
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.Console({
                json: true,
                colorize: true
            })
        ],
        // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
        meta: true,
        // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
        msg: 'HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}',
        // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting, with the same colors.
        // Enabling this will override any msg and colorStatus if true. Will only output colors on transports with colorize set to true
        expressFormat: true,
        // Color the status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red). Will not be recognized if expressFormat is true
        colorStatus: true,
        ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
            return false;
        } // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
    });

    return wistonMiddleware;
};
```

But, you can you other winston modules to log in a different way like to elastic search: https://github.com/vanthome/winston-elasticsearch